# Problemas ao retornar uma grande quantidade de dados pelo WCF

Tags: c#, web-service, wcf

Boa Tarde,

tenho um web service feito em WCF, quando faço uma consulta no banco e retorno uma grande quantidade de registros ele me da o seguinte erro:

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: A cota máxima de tamanho de mensagens de entrada (65536) foi excedida. Para aumentar a cota, use a propriedade MaxReceivedMessageSize no elemento de associação apropriado.**

alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Você deve aumentar a propriedade `maxReceivedMessageSize` no `binding` do seu cliente. Como o seu cliente é definido? Usando `ChannelFactory` diretamente, usando uma classe gerada pelo `Add Service Reference`, de alguma outra forma?

Comment: Carlos, está definida pela classe gerada pelo Add Service Reference

Comment: Aumentei a Propriedade maxReceivedMessageSize, maxBufferSiz,maxBufferPoolSize e deu Certo , Obrigado !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quando você usa o "Add Service Reference" para gerar o cliente para o WCF service, essa ferramenta adiciona no seu arquivo de configuração (app.config ou web.config) as informações necessárias para o cliente se comunicar com o servidor. Uma delas é o `binding` a ser usado.

Você pode alterar a configuração do `binding` para aumentar esta quota que a mensagem de erro está dizendo que está sendo ultrapassada. Por exemplo:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding
        name="BasicHttpBinding_MyService"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Uma outra alternativa é fazer isso no código, antes de chamar uma função do cliente pela primeira vez, como no exemplo abaixo.

```
        var c = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient();
        var binding = c.Endpoint.Binding;
        if (binding is BasicHttpBinding)
        {
            ((BasicHttpBinding)binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
        }
        else if (binding is WSHttpBinding)
        {
            ((WSHttpBinding)binding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
        }
        else
        {
            // outros tipos
            var newBinding = new CustomBinding(binding);
            for (var i = 0; i < newBinding.Elements.Count; i++)
            {
                if (newBinding.Elements[i] is TransportBindingElement) {
                    ((TransportBindingElement)newBinding.Elements[i]).MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1000000;
                }
            }

            c.Endpoint.Binding = newBinding;
        }
```

Comment: Resolvido , Obrigado carlosfigueira